# Google Analytics integration with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to intergrate google analytics api with laravel. I am following this tutorial [HelloAnalytics.php](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) but so far I am faced with an obstacle. I have reached the part `Code Summary: Authentication and Authorization` and I am faced with multiple errors so far.
Here's my code:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {


   public function analytics()
   {
        session_start();

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client = new apiClient(); //that's the one supposed to be there but I got Class 'apiClient' not found so I changed it to the one above
        $client->setApplicationName('Hello Analytics API Sample');

        // Visit https://console.developers.google.com/ to generate your
        // client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
        $client->setClientId('id');
        $client->setClientSecret('secret');
        $client->setRedirectUri('redirect_uri');
        $client->setDeveloperKey('apikey');
        $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));

        // Magic. Returns objects from the Analytics Service instead of associative arrays.
        $client->setUseObjects(true); //This line also causes an error stating Call to undefined method Google_Client::setUseObjects()

        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
          $client->authenticate();
          $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
          $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
          header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
          $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        }

        if (!$client->getAccessToken()) {
          $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
          print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";

        } else {
          $analytics = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);//Also another error here: Class 'Google_AnalyticsService' not found
          runMainDemo($analytics);
        }

   }
}
```

In my php.in file, I have added the following:

```
include_path=".:/usr/local/share/pear:/usr/local/PEAR:C:\xampp\htdocs\google-api-php-client\src"
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: how have you installed the google libs? If installed via composer, the function and class names could change from the tutorial!!